# Github Activity Graph

Tags: github

I have recently contributed some files to my github account. You can find it under [here](https://github.com/FabianFalck). The contributions are correctly displayed in the contribution activity under the graph. However, the graph does not update (the squares don't become green). I have read all the helps from Github, checked out dozens of webpages, but I simply can't find a solution. Can you guys do?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Did anything work here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try another web browser, or [clean your browser cache](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache)?

I see the green square on graph for 3 contributions from "Sep 18, 2016".

It will probably be something with caching in your web browser.

Comment: I tried safari now, previously used google chrome. However, even if I cleaned the browser cache, the squares don't become green. Though it is a good sign if you can see them, then it must definitely be an error on my machine...

Comment: I tried now a few other browsers, but whatever I do, the green square does not appear. Can anyone confirm that the graph does change?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't quite enough to go off here so I'm going to go out on a limb.

My guess is that you had the repo and everything was fine. Then you got a new computer, downloaded the files, are able to change and push but (as you mentioned) no credit the work you did. If that's the case, what is likely is that you have a config problem. Github is crediting someone or something else, just not you.

How to fix it:

`git config --global user.name "<your github user name>"`

`git config --global user.email "<the email account you have for github>"`

How to tell:

I put this last because the fix is simply easier to do.

On your computer and in the repo that isn't getting credit type
`git blame <file you've made recent changes>`. Look for two different names. Unfortunately, it doesn't show email but use this as a first go. If you don't see any differences and there is a chance (hence the reason to simply do the fix first) no email is configured or the two emails differ.

`git blame --line-porcelain <file you've made recent changes>`

From there carefully look at the first two lines (author and author-mail) and look for discrepancies.